# VS Code not logging in terminal

Tags: node.js, windows, visual-studio-code

I am using VS Code on Windows 10 for the first time, I have installed NPM and Node but when I try Console logging I get a blank response

code below

```
var g = "l"

console.log(g)
```

I ran on command prompt and powershell, `node ind.js`, ind.js is the name of the file

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please edit your question to show steps to reproduce your issue. How do you run the script, in which tab of the VSCode console do you expect to show the `console.log`, etc... For example, using only the input from your current question, I was not able to reproduce the issue and was able to open the terminal included in VSCode (on Mac, but it should be very similar on Win), open the `node` interactive console and print out the output - https://imgur.com/xBip4Vt

Comment: @PetrHejda thank you for your guidance and for investing the time. I've edited my response to show the tab I used and the file, is there anything else that you would need to know?